# something confusing about select function's usage

Tags: sockets, networking

```
  1 #include "mynet.h"
  2 #include <sys/select.h>
  3 #include <sys/time.h>
  4 
  5 #define BUF_SIZE 100
  6 
  7 int main(int argc, char** argv)
  8 {
  9         int serv_sock, cli_sock;
 10         struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 11         struct timeval timeout;
 12         fd_set reads, cpy-reads;
 13 
 14         socklen_t cli_addr_size;
 15 
 16         int fd_max, str_len, fd_num, i;
 17 
 18         char buf[BUF_SIZE];
 19 
 20         if(argc!=2)
 21         {
 22                 printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
 23                 exit(1);
 24         }
 25 
 26         serv_sock=Socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 27 
 28         memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
 29 
 30         serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET
 31         serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
 32         serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 33 
 34         Bind(serv_sock, (sa*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 35 
 36         Listen(serv_sock, 5);
 37 
 38         FD_ZERO(&reads);
 39         FD_SET(serv_sock, &reads);
 40         fd_max=serv_sock;
 41 
 42         while(1)
 43         {
 44                 cpy_reads=reads;
 45                 timeout.tv_sec=5;
 46                 timeout.tv_usec=5000;
 47 
 48                 if((fd_num=select(fd_max+1, &cpy_reads, 0, 0, &timeout))==-1)
 49                         break;
 50                 if(fd_num==0)
 51                         continue;
 52 
 53                 for(i=0; i<fd_max+1; i++)
 54                 {
 55                         if(FD_ISSET(i, &cpy_reads))
 56                         {
 57                                 if(i==serv_sock)
 58                                 {
 59                                         cli_addr_size=sizeof(cli_addr);
 60                                         cli_sock=Accept(serv_sock, (sa*)&cli_addr, &cli_addr_size);
 61                                         FD_SET(cli_sock, &reads);
 62 
 63                                         if(fd_max<cli_sock)
 64                                                 fd_max=cli_sock;
 65                                         printf("connected client: %d \n", cli_sock);
 66                                 }
 67                                 else
 68                                 {
 69                                         str_len=read(i, buf, BUF_SIZE);
 70                                         if(str_len==0)
 71                                         {
 72                                                 FD_CLR(i, &reads);
 73                                                 close(i);
 74                                                 printf("closed client: %d \n", i);
 75                                         }
 76                                         else
 77                                                 write(i, buf, str_len);
 78                                 }
 79                         }
 80                 }
 81         }
 82 
 83         close(serv_sock);
 84 
 85         return 0;
 86 }
```

I have question about above source code, which is in my book's example.
My problem is when there are clients which is connected to server.

In this situation(has some clients), another bad client sends SYN packet(don't reply to server's SYN/ACK packet) to server, so select function returns about sent message of serv_sock. Finally, because of this, server will call `Accept()` function. But it's blocked from `Accept()` function, because it's uncompleted connection request(contrast to completed connection request which is done by 3way handshake).

So, here, server is blocked from `Accept()` function. In this situation, when client sends message to server. Server can't call `read()` function, because it's blocked from `Accept()` function.

What I write above is right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is when there are clients which is connected to server.

No it isn't. Your problem has nothing to do with clients connected to the server. It is about clients which *fail to complete* a connection to the server.

> In this situation(has some clients), another bad client sends SYN packet(don't reply to server's SYN/ACK packet) to server, so select function returns about sent message of serv_sock.

No it doesn't. You made this up. It will return when a complete connection exists on the backlog queue. Your example is not a completed connection and is not a candidate for triggering `select().`

> Finally, because of this, server will call Accept() function.

No. It will still be blocked in `select().`

> But it's blocked from Accept() function, because it's uncompleted connection request(contrast to completed connection request which is done by 3way handshake).

No, it's blocked in `select()`, for that reason.

> So, here, server is blocked from Accept() function.

No.

> In this situation, when client sends message to server. Server can't call read() function, because it's blocked from Accept() function.

No.

> What I write above is right?

No.